# Cherrypy download serve_file

Tags: python, cherrypy

I am attempting to create a zip file and the allow it to be downloaded from the webpage.  I am able to get it to serve the file but instead of downloading in the browser, it makes the call and serves it as the body of the response.  I just want to download the file.

```
def download(self, **kwargs):
        filename = kwargs["filename"]
        path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), filename)
        return cherrypy.lib.static.serve_file(path, "application/x-download", "attachment", os.path.basename(path))
download.exposed = True
```

When i use chrome's inspect tools on the response from /download i can see that the content-type and disposition headers are set as expected, and can see the zip content in the response section.  However, I just want to download the file.  I had this working at one point but now can't seem to get it going again.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/x-download
Server: CherryPy/18.6.1
Date: Wed, 01 Jun 2022 20:14:59 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 01 Jun 2022 20:04:11 GMT
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="benny.txt"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 14
```

Comment: I was doing some testing and set the filename to a text file, "benny.txt", but same results.

Answer (score 0):

I have a CherryPy application where I do something similar and it works.  Here is what the code I have looks like:

```
    def getzip(self, dirpath=None):
        zipfile = os.path.join(ziplink, 'hostmaps/%s' % dirpath)
        return static.serve_file(zipfile, 'application/x-download', 'attachment', os.path.basename(zipfile))
```

Using jinja2 template, I have a link to download the zip from the HTML like this:

```
<p><a href="getzip?dirpath={{ zipfile }}">Download zip archive</a></p>
```

Hope this helps!